# What are the units for MapPoint M value with spatial reference WGS 84?

Tags: coordinate-system, line, wgs84, units

Is this something I can convert to miles or meters? What is the equation?

Comment: The unit of measure for WGS 84 (http://www.epsg-registry.org/?display=entity&urn=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) is degrees

Comment: Note you seem to have three questions, and as such your question is likely to be closed as being too broad.  The title should be a summary of the question in the body of the question, but it seems to be a different separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If M value is a measure value, there's no information about what unit it might be using when the xy coordinate system is geographic. The spatial reference doesn't have a unit for the measures.

If the xy coordinate system is projected, you can guess that the measures are using the same unit, but that may not always be the case. As an example, the measures might represent mile markers but the xy coordinate system might be using feet.